# Creating Drupal taxonomy terms from code?

Tags: php, drupal, taxonomy

What is the function used to create taxonomy terms in Drupal from the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't check the API docs? The answer is right there. http://api.drupal.org/api/function/taxonomy_save_term/6

Comment: Awesome. Now where to get an example of how to use it?

Comment: +1 - This is the function to use, as it will invoke the appropriate hooks. NOTE: The function is a bit awkward to use, as it expects its parameter to be an array of the structure of a single term coming from the term edit page, which can vary a bit.

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of the page and read the comment, you'll find the example there.

Comment: @RD: Ahem - have you scrolled down to the bottom of the linked API doc page? Simple example right there ;)

Comment: Yip. Just caught my eye now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A module I was writing needed a specific vocabulary with hierarchical terms. I wrote this function to save the terms:

```
<?php
/**
 * Save recursive array of terms for a vocabulary.
 *
 * Example:
 * <code><?php
 * $terms = array(
 *   'Species' => array(
 *     'Dog',
 *     'Cat',
 *     'Bird' ),
 *   'Sex' => array(
 *     'Male',
 *     'Female' ) )
 * _save_terms_recursive( $vid, $terms );
 * </code>
 *
 * @param int $vid Vocabulary id
 * @param array $terms Recursive array of terms
 * @param int $ptid Parent term id (generated by taxonomy_save_term) 
 */
function _save_terms_recursive( $vid, &$terms, $ptid=0 ) {
  foreach ( $terms as $k => $v ) {
    // simple check for numeric indices (term array without children)
    $name = is_string( $k ) ? $k : $v;
    $term = array( 'vid' => $vid, 'name' => $name, 'parent' => $ptid );
    taxonomy_save_term( $term );
    if ( is_array( $v ) && count( $v ) )
      _save_terms_recursive( $vid, $terms[ $k ], $term[ 'tid' ] );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 7, it's [taxonomy_term_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_save/7), by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 7 version looks like this:

```
/**
 * Save recursive array of terms for a vocabulary.
 *
 * Example of an array of terms:
 * $terms = array(
 *   'Species' => array(
 *     'Dog',
 *     'Cat',
 *     'Bird' ),
 *   'Sex' => array(
 *     'Male',
 *     'Female' ) );
 *
 * @param int $vid Vocabulary id
 * @param array $terms Recursive array of terms
 * @param int $ptid Parent term id (generated by taxonomy_save_term, when =0 then no parent)
 *
 * taxonomy_term_save ($term) gives back saved tid in $term
 * 
 **/
function _save_terms_recursively( $vid, &$terms, $ptid=0 ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $k => $v ) {
        // simple check for numeric indices (term array without children)
        $name = is_string( $k ) ? $k : $v;

        $term = new stdClass();
        $term->vid = $vid;
        $term->name = $name;
        $term->parent = $ptid;
        taxonomy_term_save( $term );

        if ( is_array( $v ) && count( $v ) ) {
            _save_terms_recursively( $vid, $terms[ $k ], $term->tid );
        }
    }
```