# Where in code do I add taxonomy_save_vocabulary for drupal module

Tags: drupal

I know that in order to programmatically add my own taxonomy to a node I need to use the **[taxonomy_save_vocabulary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424120/creating-drupal-taxonomy-terms-from-code)** function and pass it an array defining my vocabulary.  But I need to know where does this code usually go in the module.  I'm assuming the **install file?**

Thanks!

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The install file is for initial set up of your module - setting up database tables and clearing up for uninstall, basically. So yes, if you're adding a taxonomy just once, and especially if it's indispensible to your module, this would be a good place to do it.

More ideas about this here:
http://sachachua.com/wp/2009/04/drupal-staging-and-deployment-tips-its-all-code/